# PostgreSQL: unique constraint or unique index

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, unique-constraint, unique-index

Should I create unique index if a column contains unique constraint and I want to fast search by this column?

For example I have a table `users` with column `login` that should be unique. I need fast search user by the `login` column.

Which is the best way to do it:

1. create a unique constraint (it creates internal unique index - is it used in select queries with `WHERE login = 'something'`?)
2. create a unique index
3. create a unique index and unique constraint (index duplicates internal index?)

Second case is unique `login` on not locked users (column `locked = false`). Postgres does not support partial conditions. Should I create a unique conditional and a partial index or is only a partial index enough?

And one more question: should I create new index for a column with a foreign key? For example: `users.employee_id` relates to `employees.id`, should I create an index on `employee` column for optimized query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE employee_id = ....`? When are internal indexes used by the optimization engine and when not?

Answer (score 7):

> I have a table 'users' with column login that should be unique

If this is the case you need a unique constraint. Unique constraints are enforced (behind the scenes) by unique indexes.

Conceptually:

- The unique constraint *defines* the uniqueness.
- The unique index *implements* the unique constraint.
- The unique index provides speedy searches since it allows operations such as Index Range Scan and Index Seeks.

> Is it used in select queries with WHERE login = 'something'?

Yes, it is.

> Second case is unique login on not locked users (column locked = false).

If this is the case a `unique` constraint won't work. Maybe a trigger on insert could help here.

> should I create new index for column with foreign key?

No, it's not needed (at least in the current version `10` and perhaps the later versions), s. [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/indexes-unique.html):

> PostgreSQL automatically creates a unique index when a unique constraint or primary key is defined for a table. [...] There's no need to manually create indexes on unique columns; doing so would just duplicate the automatically-created index.

Comment: @automatix I think PostgreSQL does not create indexes for foreign keys by default, and your edit may be incorrect. The documentation you included is related to unique indexes, not foreign keys.

Comment: Unfortunately I read the quote wrong. The context of the question was the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`, so I read the text as "should I create new index for column with _unique constraint_?". So, yes, my edit _is_ incorrect. Please reject it.