# Unique constraint vs index - Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In **Postgres 11** if I add a **unique index** `IX_A_B` on 2 columns `(A,B)`
is that enough to ensure no duplicate pairs can be inserted
say (5,4) on one row, and (5,4) on another row?

Or... do I need to also add a unique constraint based on the unique index?

```
ALTER TABLE TBL    
ADD CONSTRAINT unique_A_B 
UNIQUE USING INDEX IX_A_B;
```

Also, if I don't need the unique constraint then...
what is the purpose of having such constraints at all?

**NOTE**: I just tried it, seems the constraint is not needed.
Then I am confused... what is the idea behind unique constraints,
and behind this syntax/command above in particular?

Comment: Or maybe [PostgreSQL: unique constraint or unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51003943/479863), [Unique constraint vs. unique index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32886581/479863), [Should I specify both INDEX and UNIQUE INDEX?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4531693/479863), [Does a Postgres UNIQUE constraint imply an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29655439/479863), ...

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will take a look and delete my question. Sorry.

Comment: It may just be a matter of completeness and preference. By preference I always create a constraint not just an index.